# UpdateView creating new object instead of altering original

Tags: django, django-views

I will start this with I know this has been asked but I looked through those answers and not of them were the solution here.

views.py:

```
class JobUpdateView(UpdateView):
    model = Job
    form_class = JobForm
    template_name = 'job/edit_job.html'
```

urls.py:

```
path('edit/<int:pk>/', job_views.JobUpdateView.as_view(), name='edit_job'),
```

template (included the `<form>` I use to delete objects just in case that was having some effect):

```
    {% for job in jobs  %}
          <button ><a href="{% url 'edit_job' job.id %}" >Edit</a></button>  <!-- edit-->
          <form class="" action="{% url 'delete_job' pk=job.id %}" method="post"> <!--delete-->
            {% csrf_token %}
            <input type ='hidden' name ='job_id' value='{{ job.id }}'/>
            <button type="submit">Delete</button>
          </form>
        </div>
   {% endfor %}
```

This will display a list of the user's posts, if the users clicks 'edit' on a specific post it will display the proper object and its contents in a form to be edited. But, when the user saves that form, instead of editing the original object there are now two objects, the original and whatever was changed. Not sure why this happening?

Comment: Can you share the `JobForm` and the `job/edit_job.html` template? Did you do anything special with that?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem honestly did not look in edit_job.html, think I copy and pasted my post_job.html and never changed the form action because it was pointing to my `post_job` view... My mistake but thanks I don't think I would have realized that for quite awhile.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem being that was a silly error on my part should I close the question?